# Gephi uploading csv file or choosing sample Les Miserables.gexf on the opening page of Gephi throws java.util.MissingResourceException error

Tags: csv, upload, gephi

Below is the complete error message that Gephi gives me - when I try to upload a csv file.

I have java version: java version "1.8.0_221" and gephi version 0.9.2.
My java works very well,I set the environment variables and tested it.And I also configure the --jdkhome path settings as following

```
jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221" // in gephi.conf file.
```

But that didn't work for me.After that I've tried that right click on Gephi icon,choose properties,edit target as following

```
"C:\Program Files\Gephi-0.9.2\bin\gephi64.exe" --jdkhome "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221"
```

I read that sentence also in Gephi.com "Java is bundled with the application so it doesn't have to be installed separately. On Windows and Linux, the system must be equipped with Java." what does it mean?

But that also didn't work. Any help will be appreciated !!

I've searched all of the internet generally people get the Error: " Java has not been found ".But this is not my problem mine is opening without any error. And then when I try to upload for example Nodes1.csv file it gives the following error.

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle org.openide.util.NbBundle$PBundle, key ReportPanel.mergeStrategy.mın
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getString(Unknown Source)
    at org.openide.util.NbBundle.getMessage(NbBundle.java:642)
    at org.gephi.desktop.importer.EdgesMergeStrategyWrapper.toString(EdgesMergeStrategyWrapper.java:90)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsComboBoxUI$WindowsComboBoxRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI.getDisplaySize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI.getMinimumSize(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsComboBoxUI.getMinimumSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.GetLayoutInfo(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.getLayoutInfo(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.ArrangeGrid(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.arrangeGrid(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.layoutContainer(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
[catch] at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What is your problem about this. Please make your question easy to read.

Comment: Sounds like something you should ask the people working on gephi about, but you should tell them as much as you can about how you installed it, where you installed it from, the exact steps you took to get that error. Providing the CSV file would be very useful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a java version 1.8 both JDK and JRE in program files. I just removed java and just download JRE 1.8  runtime environment and it worked. And please pay attention that When multiple JRE or JDK are installed on the same machine, you can specify to Gephi to use a particular path. Edit gephi.conf as described in the upper section, uncomment the jdkhome line and set the JRE or JDK path.

Comment: I have already JRE 1.8 but I am getting the same errror

Comment: your problem may be the Gephi program language then, try to change it to English.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did so and it has worked